# manipulate caller id for verified or twilio numbers

Tags: twilio

We need to pass along some information and caller id is the only field our call center can receive. Is it possible to manipulate caller id for calls going to verified or twilio phone numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Are you connecting to your call center via a normal PSTN dial?  If yes, then there are [pretty strict rules](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-caller-id?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) around what you can set in the CallerId attribute.

If you are dialing your call center using the [`<Sip>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sip?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) noun then you have some more flexibility to include extra metadata that Twilio will convert into [custom SIP headers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sip#custom-headers?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon).

Hope that helps.